# GSON JsonObject and LinkedTreeMap

Tags: java, generics, gson

I noticed there wasn't an easy all-inclusive (POJO-free) way to convert (in GSON) a `JsonArray` to a `List`. I found an example that uses a `TypeToken` and when I tried to use move this to a generic method (I'm a little hazy on my Java Generics), I found some odd behavior where `JsonObject` and `LinkedTreeMap` were confused. See example below:

```
public <T> List<T> jsonArrayToList(JsonArray array, Class<T> clazz) {
    Gson GSON = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.getType();
    return GSON.fromJson(array,listType);
}

@Test
public void testGson() {
    Gson GSON = new Gson();
    String jsonString = "[ {key:\"foo\",value:\"bar\"}, {key:\"shoe\",value:\"car\"} ]";
    JsonArray testArray = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<JsonObject>>() {}.getType();
    List<JsonObject> goodList = GSON.fromJson(testArray,listType);
    List<JsonObject> badList = jsonArrayToList(testArray, JsonObject.class);    // Actually a list of LinkedTreeMap?

    System.out.println( goodList );     // [{"key":"foo","value":"bar"}, {"key":"shoe","value":"car"}]
    System.out.println( badList );      // [{key=foo, value=bar}, {key=shoe, value=car}]

    try {
        long shoeCount = goodList.stream().filter(o -> o.get("key").getAsString().startsWith("sh")).count();
        System.out.println( shoeCount );    // 1
    } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println( e.getMessage() ); }

    try {
        long shoeCount = badList.stream().filter(o -> o.get("key").getAsString().startsWith("sh")).count();
        System.out.println( shoeCount );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject
    }
}
```

I'm just curious why this occurs and/or if the generic method is incorrect.

Comment: It's not a Gson issue. The implementation of `jsonArrayToList` is broken since `T` is _erased_ (due to how generics work in Java) implementing `TypeVariable` and not implementing `ParameterizedType`, hence unknown at runtime even if you invoke the method with a valid type token.

Comment: The proper way to make it work is passing a type (or type token holder, does not matter per se) that already holds all necessary type information. Say, something like `private static <T> List<T> jsonArrayToList(final TypeToken<List<T>> typeToken, final JsonArray array) { return gson.fromJson(array, typeToken.getType()); }` but I doubt that you need such a method at all then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72034979/gson-jsonobject-and-linkedtreemap#comment127288360_72034979), due to Java type erasure, the `TypeToken<List<T>>` is actually a `TypeToken<List<Object>>` at runtime, regardless of what value `T` has. When Gson is told to deserialize as `Object` it uses a Java type corresponding to the JSON data, for your JSON object that is `java.util.Map` (with Gson's implementation `LinkedTreeMap`).

In general you should therefore never use any type variables when creating a `TypeToken` (unfortunately Gson itself does not prevent this usage).

For your specific use case you can use the method [`TypeToken.getParameterized`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html#getParameterized(java.lang.reflect.Type,java.lang.reflect.Type...)). With that you can create parameterized types with type arguments specified at runtime. This comes at the cost of missing type safety at compile time, so you have to make sure to provide the correct number of arguments to `getParameterized` depending on the generic type (e.g. `Map<K, V>` requires two type arguments) and that they do not validate the type bounds of the type variable.

Here is how you could use it in your method `jsonArrayToList`:

```java
public <T> List<T> jsonArrayToList(JsonArray array, Class<T> clazz) {
    Gson GSON = new Gson();
    Type listType = TypeToken.getParameterized​(List.class, clazz).getType();
    return GSON.fromJson(array,listType);
}
```